# passing command line arguments to ant

Tags: ant, command-line-arguments

I am relatively new in ant, at school I have an assignment to do a build file. One of my questions is to copy to "/foldercopy" the file whose name(or path) is taken as argument for ant. I need to do something like:

ant cpfile file.txt

So ant will copy the file.txt to /foldercopy. I searched a lot on google but all I could find was something with "-Darg", but my teacher said that it's not correct. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Plain command line arguments to `ant` are considered to be target names, so if you want to pass arguments to your target you need to use properties, via `-D`:

```
ant -Dfile=file.txt cpfile
```

and access the value as `${file}` inside build.xml

Answer (score -4):

This will help you:

```
<target name="copytask" >
  <copy file="file.txt" todir="path-od-dir" failonerror="false" />

</target>
```