# pass line arguments to main from ant

Tags: java, ant, terminal, arguments, program-entry-point

My question is How can I catch the arguments in the terminal using ant to run the main with these parameters,
example:

```
    ant 1 2 3 4 5
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      int[] meta = {0,0,0,0,0};
      for(int i=1; i < 6; i++)
      {
        meta[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
      }
    }
```

How can i do this, somebody help me pls C:?
 Here my build.xml

```
<project name="Tarea2LP" basedir="." default="main">

<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="jar"/>
<property name="main-class"  value="Board"/>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="${jar.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">

    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>

<target name="main" depends="run"/>

</project>
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309406/passing-command-line-arguments-to-ant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of arguments is known you can use the -D option to pass in the argument and then in your "run" task target use 'arg' to pass it to jar file like

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">

    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true">
        <arg value="${arg1}"/>
        <arg value="${arg2}"/>
        <arg value="${arg3}"/>
        <arg value="${arg4}"/>
        <arg value="${arg5}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

and you should invoke your ant file as

```
ant -Darg1=1 -Darg2=2 -Darg3=3 -Darg4=4 -Darg5=5
```

Comment: tyyyyyyyyyy thats worked perfectly <3, but if the numbers of argument is zero, how can i fix that error? Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${arg1}"

Comment: As i said it works only if the number of arguments are known. Idont think ant support varargs. However the exception is being thrown from you java class. Its expecting an integer argument but it received "${arg1}" since no -Darg1 was set. You might have to handle this in your java class.

Comment: You can also set default values for these args with ant <property> statements (e.g. <property name="arg1" value=""/> - the values passed in to ant will override the defaults (since property values in ant can't be changed once set).